Transformers Trainer: Tried to track the number of tokens seen, however the current model is not configured properly to know what item is the input
I'm receiving this error from HuggingFace's Trainer:
Tried to track the number of tokens seen, however the current model is not configured properly to know what item is the input. To fix this, add a `main_input_name` attribute to the model class you are using. 

This is with the model "google/gemma-2b-it". I'm using PyTorch. How do I fix this?

This is a guess, because I've not seen this feature before, but looking at the documentations (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/main_classes/model#transformers.PreTrainedModel) there's a main_input_name property of PretrainedModel. My guess is it was added after the model you're using was trained.

You could try setting it explicitly after loading the model, i.e. model=AutoModel.from_pretrained ..., model.main_input_name="input_ids" or whatever the main input is
